# Write Text on an NSImage in Swift-OSX

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I have the following objective C Code to write text onto an Image. I'm new to Swift. How can I do this in Swift?

```
float width = 10.0;
float height = 10.0;

NSImage *finalImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(width, height)];

//  obtain images - your sources may vary
NSImage *overlay = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/overlay_image.jpg"]];
NSImage *mainImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/main_image.jpg"]];

[finalImage lockFocus];

// draw the base image
[mainImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height) 
                      fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

// draw the overlay image at some offset point
[overlay drawInRect:NSMakeRect(10, 10, [overlay size].width, [overlay size].height) 
             fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

[finalImage unlockFocus];

NSData *finalData = [finalImage TIFFRepresentation];

[[[NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:finalData] representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil] writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/path/to/folder/new_image.jpg"] atomically:YES];
```

**UPDATE:**

I have the following method to draw a string onto an Image..But it when I use this method I get cropped out image portions..Seems something is wrong with it..Please advice.

```
func drawText(image :NSImage) ->NSImage
{
    let text = "Sample Text"
    let font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

    let textRect = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: image.size.width - 5, height: image.size.height - 5)
    let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: font,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.white,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle
    ]

    let im:NSImage = NSImage(size: image.size)

    let rep:NSBitmapImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: Int(image.size.width), pixelsHigh: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)!

    im.addRepresentation(rep)

    im.lockFocus()

    image.draw(in: imageRect)
    text.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    im.unlockFocus()

    return im
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow is not a code conversion service. The code is pretty straightforward. With the help of code completion (and a bit reading the documentation) it's quite easy to convert.

Comment: @vadian okay ...... :(

Comment: which swift version are you using?

Comment: @Malik Im using Swift 3.. Xcode 8

Comment: @vadian Please see my update.

Comment: Your code works so good. Thanks . it saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

Here's this code in **Swift 3**

```
let width: CGFloat = 10.0
let height: CGFloat = 10.0

let finalImage = NSImage(size: NSMakeSize(width, height))

//  obtain images - your sources may vary
var overlay: NSImage?
var mainImage: NSImage?

if let url = URL(string: "/path/to/overlay_image.jpg") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        overlay = NSImage(data: data)
    } catch {
        print("Unable to get data")
    }
}

if let url = URL(string: "/path/to/main_image.jpg") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        mainImage = NSImage(data: data)
    } catch {
        print("Unable to get data")
    }
}

finalImage.lockFocus()

// draw the base image
mainImage?.draw(in: NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height), from: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)

// draw the overlay image at some offset point
if overlay != nil {
    overlay?.draw(in: NSMakeRect(10, 10, overlay!.size.width, overlay!.size.height), from: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.sourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
}

finalImage.unlockFocus()

if let finalData = finalImage.tiffRepresentation, let url = URL(string: "/path/to/folder/new_image.jpg") {
    do {
        try NSBitmapImageRep(data: finalData)?.representation(using: NSJPEGFileType, properties: [:])?.write(to: url)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to write")
    }
}
```

Comment: `URL(string:` expects an URL string including the `file://` scheme. For file system URLs you have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:`. By the way: `NSImage` has API to get an image from an URL directly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the url mentioned in OP's question is a dummy URL as evident by the naming convention.

Comment: The ObjC code `dataWithContentsOfFile` implies clearly a file in the local file system.

Comment: It would've taken you less time to post an answer to help the OP out compared to the time it took you to write all these comments :D

Comment: @Malik Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @techno. In your original question, you only wanted a swift equivalent to the objective-C code. Instead of updating the existing question, I would recommend to post it as a new question so that the next visitor to this question doesn't get confused.

Comment: @Malik The Objective c code which I have posted was the closest I could find.But I have also mentioned that I need to draw string on an image.Could you please tell me whats wrong with the second code I have posted.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with mac os development so will be needing a bit of understanding here. For starters, what is the link between the two code snippets (i.e. the obj-C code and the drawText method)?